# Как полностью заменить файлы на сервере на файлы из удалённой ветки

Tags: git, gitlab

Ситуация такая - есть тестовый сервер и есть рабочий сервер, весь проект хранится на гитлабе, если делаются какие-то правки, то создаётся ветка на гитлаб, и потом для переноса, я подключаюсь по ssh к серверу и от его лица делаю git pull origin 'нужная ветка'. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что на тестовом сервере скопилось слишком много не нужных правок. На гитлабе у меня есть ветка с полной копией проекта. Я хочу перенести эту копию на тестовый сайт, но когда я делаю git pull origin name_branch файлы просто сливаются и все ненужные мне ошибки продолжают оставаться. Как можно принудительно заменить полностью файлы на сервере на файлы из ветки гитлаба?

Comment: `git reset --hard origin name_branch`.

Comment: спасибо большое)